# How to establish Entity Framework Core for Mysql database "view"? C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Appreciate some guidance and direction here, please.

I was able to import all database tables with `Scaffold-DbContext` and `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` but not the views. I have searched and found mixed answers.

Is there a way to set up the views, I believe it is referred to as EF Core keyless entity types. I am new to EF Core, ultimately I would like to bind the view data to DatagridView data source.

- VS2022
- .Net 6
- Windows Application
- MySql

Comment: Already implemented https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/896 - which EF Core version?

Comment: @ErikEJ thank you for pointing this out.. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore{6.0.7}`. Appreciate help with how to reverse engineer Views then, it seems when I run `Scaffold-DbContext` only tables show up.

Comment: Suggest you create an issue in the Pomelo GitHub repo with a simple repro and any other details.